# How to prevent the split environment from placing the equation number on a new line?

Tags: split

I have written a few long equations using the `split` environment, and the compiled output of one is shown in the appended screenshot. For this equation in particular, the equation number (5.4) appears one line below the final equation line, while in other examples it appeared vertically centred on the right hand side. I suspect this behaviour is due to the page width being exceeded. In the pictured case, I would like the equation number to not appear on a new line. One suggested style is to have it appear on the same vertical position as the final equation line (after the comma). Is there any way to enforce this?

Alternatively, any suggestions on how to rewrite the equation to fit on the page? In that case, note that M and R are noncommutative matrices.

[image]

The code in the example relies quite heavily on custom macros, so I doubt it is useful to include the full required code. However, the structure is like this:

```
\begin{equation}
   \label{eq:reduced_rayleigh_expanded}
   \begin{split}
      li & ne 1 \\
      &+ line 2 \\
      &+ line 3 \\
      &+ line 4 \\
      =&\ line 5 \\
      &+ line 6,
   \end{split}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Ideally you should not have any problems with the equation numbering when you use split functionality unless your equation in each line is still too long. You can try to split again.

Comment: You haven't provided an example so no output shown here but you can use `\raisetag{20pt}` or whatever looks right to adjust the position of the equation number if the outer environment is an ams environment such as `gather`.

Comment: To the contrary, the precise code is necessary to give advice on how to split the display in a better fashion, including the document class and the font package used.

Comment: @fromthebeeland The issue here is that the equation number is generated by `equation` which looks at the width of the whole mathematical contents and decides to put the equation number on a line of its own. So, to address the OPs alternate formulation of solving the problem, splitting lines 1 and 5 (the longest lines in the equation) would bring the equation number up to middle of the set of lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  \label{eq:reduced_rayleigh_expanded}
  li & ne 1 \nonumber\\
  &+ line 2 \nonumber\\
  &+ line 3 \nonumber\\
  &+ line 4 \nonumber\\
  =&\ line 5 \nonumber\\
  &+ line 6,
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]